# Showing a photo after a button is clicked

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to have a picture I made show up after a button is clicked.

So far, I have this:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <a href="#/" title="Help page" class="btn btn-warning">Help</a>
```

But I don't know how to show a photo after the button is clicked. Any help?

To be clear let me provide an example:

When we are Googling an image, and find a picture we like, we click on "View image", and then it takes us to a new page with that picture. Similarly, I have a button called "Help", and after I click it, I want to also go to a new page with my picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading your question carefully, this will do just that. When the button is clicked, a new page will appear with your image:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <a href="path/to/your/img.jpg" title="Help page" class="btn btn-warning">Help</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The real question is *how* do you want to display the image?

This will display the image, but without more information, it's hard to say how to style it.

**HTML**

```
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <button id="showme">Show me the Image!</button>
 <img src="myimage.jpg" id="myimage">
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#myimage {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#showme").click(function() {
  $("#myimage").css({"display": 'block'})
});
```

Comment: Check out my updated post! Hopefully that explains what I am trying to say more...